# How to make brushing work on a viz when it needs to respond to events, such as click, hover, and so forth?

Tags: d3.js, brush

I've a viz composed of (a) stacked areas, (b) lines, (c) with hover effect, and (d) tooltips. They are all working perfectly. The only one that is not playing well with the rest is brushing.

1. if I add below any elements, the brushing event is not working where the stack area layers or lines are.
2. if I add it last, the brushing effects is present in the entire svg. However, click, hover, tooltip and everything else is gone.

Is there a way to make brushing play nice with the rest of the events?

Thanks for helping

Comment: if its an option, I would suggest that you have a ui element (say a button maybe) to enable/disable brushing events, once the brush is triggered the ui update based on brush event, and another button to reset the ui to its original state or dataset.

Comment: @mamounothman, I'm more than happy to do that as I don't see any way around that. I'm event getting other weird behavior because I combining brushing with other effects.